# run external commands from java(Android) and read continuous output

Tags: android, user-interface, android-ndk, native, bufferedreader

I want to run excutable such as ping(or any other which gives continuous output)  and read its output and print it in my GUI.

I used following method to run my commands:

```
command=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping www.google.com");
```

and I am reading the output as following:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(command.getInputStream()));

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                    System.out.println(line+"\n");
}
```

this works fine , although display output pretty late compared to time taken when i execute ./excutable using adb -d shell.

As I want to this output(line) in gui so I make a TextView and append the output(line) in it as:

```
txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                    txtview.append(line+"\n");
                    System.out.println(line+"\n");
}
```

but this crashes my application.
please tell me how to get over this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your last block of code is being executed in an `Activity`, then you are probably blocking the UI thread for too long.  This will cause Android to force close your application.  Try using `AsyncTask` to get the output and update your GUI.

Comment: But, how am I gonna read the BufferedReader using AsyncTask and display each line(as they come in the BufferedReader) in the TextView ?

Comment: You read in the text during doInBackground.  You can pass each line to  onProgressUpdate and update the UI there or you can update a class member variable.  Bottom line, you *have* to do the reading on a background thread!

Comment: How can I pass String to onProgressUpdate when it takes integer as argument?

Comment: Moreover, I cant use findViewById() so, how am I gonna find TextView and append data to it?

Comment: You define the type that onProgressUpdate takes when you create your implementation since its a generic.  The example in the JavaDoc just shows Integer, but it can be anything.  Your AsyncTask should be declared as an inner class of your Activity, so you can use findViewById.